KeyCloack not not letting admin aceess via Web after SMTP settings, how to fix?
After setting email address to Admin account(bad idea), i have not been able to log in via Web, it asks to Verify email address but that verification is not sent.
Is there a way to access via CLI and reset settings for Admin account?
Best Regards,
Feeling dumb
I did set email adresss for Admin acoount as i wanted to do SMTP settings and i wanted to test if it works by pressing Test button in SMTP settings.

Did you fix it already? If not are you using keycloak with database?

Hi! Not yet, my collegue only has access via CLI to KeyCloack and we do not have database installed yet.

If you have access to the database then you can execute following sql:
1.
postgresql / mssql:
update USER_ENTITY set EMAIL_VERIFIED = true where USERNAME = 'admin'

mssql:
update USER_ENTITY set EMAIL_VERIFIED = 1 where USERNAME = 'admin'




select ID from USER_ENTITY where USERNAME = 'admin'
delete from USER_REQUIRED_ACTION where USER_ID = '<USER_ID_FROM_FIRST_SQL'

After updating the database, a restart is necessary because of the infinispan cache. Consider to do a database backup before.

an alternative approach would be to use the keycloak cli tool for the login and editing your admin account .

Thanks we will try this with my collegue, who has CLI access to KeyCloack only.
